# PDO - Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I looked at all the other posts on this and none of them came up with exactly what my problem is so here we go:

$dbh stores my PDO connection, if I do a var dump on it, it returns:

```
object(PDO)#1 (0) { }
```

So I know my PDO connection is working.  I then use $sth to hold my query:

```
$c = 2;
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = " . $c);
```

Then to make sure this is working I did:

```
echo $sth->rowCount();
```

That return a value of 6.  So I know it is grabbing some rows.  My next step of checking my problem was to fetch a single row like the following:

```
$row = $sth->fetch()
print_r($row);
```

This returned a single row (as it should) with the $row array filled exactly how I would expect it (column names as keys and column values as the array value).

So we are good up to this point.  Once I move $row = $sth->fetch() into a while loop my script fails the error it returns is: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Here is my while loop:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()){
    //while loop stuff here
}
```

I know it has something to do with the condition of the loop because even when I comment out all the stuff in the middle it still isn't working.  What am I doing wrong?  Why won't this work?  I'm beyond confused on this as it has worked in the past with all the PDO I have done but for some reason it is failing in this script.

If anyone has any tips or something that can help it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** Since ninetwozero's post worked, I'm posting my class and basically everything I've got to get this figured out.

```
class html_elements {

var $units;
var $useMaps;
var $cid;
var $uid;
var $companyMoney;
var $currCity;
var $terminals;
var $termLocs;
var $cityArray;
var $cargoArray;
var $cargo;
var $tid;
var $truckArray;
var $load;
var $cityID;
var $cargoID;
var $xp;
var $gasPrice;
var $warning;

function __construct($u, $maps, $c, $userID, $cMoney, $dbh, $city, $tid, $xp){
    $this->units = $u;
    $this->useMaps = $maps;
    $this->cid = $c;
    $this->uid = $userID;
    $this->companyMoney = $cMoney;
    $this->currCity = $city;
    $this->terminals = array();
    $this->termLocs = array();
    $this->cityArray = array();
    $this->cargoArray = array();
    $this->cargo = array();
    $this->tid = $tid;
    $this->truckArray = array();
    $this->load = 0;
    $this->cityID = array();
    $this->cargoID = array();
    $this->xp = $xp;
    $this->gasPrice = 0;

    $sth = null;
    $sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM tblCTerminals WHERE companyID = " . $c);
            //THIS LOOP FAILS
    while($row = $sth->fetch()){
        $this->termLocs[] = $row['Location'];
    }
}
```

Then in another file that has my class file included in it is:

```
$h = new html_element($u->get_units(), $u->get_maps(), $u->get_company(), $u->get_user_id(), $c->get_money(), $dbh, $u->get_city(), $u->get_truck_id(), $u->get_xp());
```

Each of those getters work, I tested them.  Also $dbh is what is used my connection file that is included before anything else.  So I know all of that is working.

Comment: It would be great if you could post a link to a small php script reproducing the problem (with an sqlite in-memory database or so). No offense, but my guess is the query somehow failed and you forgot to turn on [exception error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: I've got error handling on, and the query works until I put it in a while loop.  Also with ninetwozero's post it is working.  So I'm posting my class and everything so we can get this figured out.

Comment: I updated my previous post with a neew snippet that you can use instead of the while-loop. Let me know if it works out as planned, otherwise we'll have to approach it differently!

Comment: That worked, still no clue why the wile loop wasn't working, but hey it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to say that you've encountered a pretty interesting error, so let's try some things to pinpoint the cause:

```
if( $sth == null ) die('My sth is null at #1');
while( $row = $sth->fetch() ) {
    if( $row == null ) die('My row is null at #2');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($row);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Let me know what this tells you.

Edit:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblCTerminals WHERE companyID = ' . $c;
if( intval($c) == 0 ) { die('Aaaaaaaaaa.......aaaaah.');
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '$row[\'Location\'] is: ' . $row['Location'] .'<br />';
    $this->termLocs[] = $row['Location'];
}
```

Comment: And now I'm more confused :(  It worked.  It printed out each row.  I have edited my post to include my class and what I'm trying to do and what is failing.  If you see something maybe we can get it figured out.